# strcmp not working and the so the program is not breaking out of the for loop even if there is a point where the two strings in strcmp become equal

Tags: c

Though word and s2 are same the if(strcmp) statement is not executed. Where is the mistake??
I checked the code for reading from a file and tried out "printf" to see whether word and s2 are the same or not and found that they become same after about 10 iterations and should break out at that point but the program executes till i is less than zero.

Please help. Thanks in advance. 
P.S "words.txt" is the inbuilt dictionary file in the fedora operating system

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
     FILE *ptr;
     ptr=fopen("./words.txt","r");
     char word[40];
     char ch;
     int i=70,j=0;
     char s2[] = "2";
     while(i>0){
          while (ch!='\n') {
               ch=fgetc(ptr);
               word[j]=ch;
               j++;
          } 
          word[j]='\0';
          if(strcmp(s2,word) == 0){
             break;
          }
          j=0; 
          if(ch=='\n'){
              ch=fgetc(ptr);
              word[j]=ch;
              j++;        
          }
          i--;
     }
     fclose(ptr); 
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: instead of `./words.txt` just give `words.txt` , else full-path

Comment: Your indentation really needs work - it was difficult for me to see that there are two loops there.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a variable before initializing its value:

```
while (ch != '\n') {
```

Anything could happen since the initial value of `ch` is not known.  However, the odds are high (255 out of 256 chances) that the expression is initially true.  After it has entered the loop once, all is well.

For the loop to work as expected, do not store `\n` in the buffer.  Since `s2` does not contain `\n`, `strcmp()` will never match as long the the newline is stored in there.

Comment: Specifically, at the first `while(i>0)` iteration `ch` is uninitialized, and after that it remains set to `'\n'` if I am not mistaken.